# How to check whether the number is same with the number in the list

Tags: python

I want to check if the number entered by the user is same with the number in the list and the way I select the item in the list using for loop to compare with the number is not working. It's like it just loop through the first item in the list.
Even when I type 43(example), it still print (43 is available in the list), I thought the first item is 65, which will not be same with 43.

```
ARR = [65,75,85,95,105]

def check_number ():
    NUM = int (input ("Please enter the number you want to check with"))
    for x in range (len (arr)):   
        check == ARR [x]
    if check == ARR [x]:
        print (NUM,"is available in the list")      
    else:
        print (NUM,"is not available is the list")
check_number ()
```

Comment: I don't think the code you pasted here works at all, because `arr` and `check` are not declared anywhere. Note that `ARR` (uppercase) and `arr` (lowercase) are not the same. This would throw a `NameError` before it even tries to run.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it, I made it uppercase because of the sakes of the error keeps popping out, which causing me cannot to post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in` keyword for comparison.

```
ARR = [65,75,85,95,105]

def check_number ():
    NUM = int (input ("Please enter the number you want to check with"))
    if NUM in ARR:
        print(NUM, ' is available in this list')
    else:
        print(NUM, ' is not available in this list')
check_number()
```

Answer (score 2):

A much better of checking whether a value (any hashable value including numbers and strings) is a member of a list is to use Python's built-in `set` type:

```py
arr = set([65, 75, 85, 95, 105])

def check_number():
    num = int (input ("Please enter the number you want to check with"))
    if num in arr:
        print (num, "is available in the list")      
    else:
        print (num, "is not available is the list")

check_number ()
```

It is both more time-efficient for larger data sets, and more idiomatic.

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
ARR = [65,75,85,95,105]

def check_number ():
    NUM = int (input ("Please enter the number you want to check with"))

    if NUM in ARR:
        print (NUM,"is available in the list")      
    else:
        print (NUM,"is not available is the list")
check_number ()
```

Using `in` to check if an array contains an element is the "[pythonic](https://medium.com/swlh/the-pythonic-way-6ad73abfbb00)" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `loop` for comparison because it `traverse` and compare the `number` with `list`. It was bit lengthy process instead of it you can use `in` for comparison between `number` and `list`. Code for the same scenario was stated below:-

```
# Declared List named 'ARR'
ARR = [65,75,85,95,105]

# Declaration of 'check_number()' function for checking whether Number is Present in list or not
def check_number ():

    # User imput of 'Number' for Comparision
    NUM = int (input ("Please enter the number you want to check with:- "))

    # If 'Number (NUM)' is present in 'List (ARR)'
    if NUM in ARR:
        print (NUM, "is available in the list") 

    # If 'Number (NUM)' is not present in 'List (ARR)'
    else:
        print (NUM, "is not available is the list")

check_number()
```

```
# Output_1 for the above code is given below:-
Please enter the number you want to check with:- 45
45 is not available is the list
```

```
# Output_2 for the above code is given below:-
Please enter the number you want to check with:- 65
65 is available in the list
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the info !